# Java: BasicClientCookie's setExpiryDate and HttpCookie's setMaxAge

Tags: java, httpcookie

I want to convert apache BasicClientCookie to java.net.HttpCookie, or the opposite. I find BasicClientCookie is missing the max-age attribute which is avaiable in HttpCookie, however, there exist the expires attribute in the BasicClientCookie.

How should I convert the max-age and expires to each other. When I get the HttpCookie, it exists for a while, then I would not know the exact expire date in BasicClientCookie? How to convert these two type cookies?

I just use it this way, but seems not very appropriate

```
    long expireMillion = System.currentTimeMillis() + maxAge*1000;
    apacheCookie.setExpiryDate(new Date(expireMillion));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are very close to the right answer.
In HttpCookie, there's a private method "setExpires" Here's the code.

```
private void setExpires(Date expires) {
maxAge = (expires.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000;}
```

So you can call setMaxAge((apacheCookie.getExpiryDate().getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000);

If you want to convert HttpCookie to apachCookie
You should override

> void add(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie)

function in java.net.CookieStore.

In this function, you can get the expiring date with following formula.

> httpCookie.getMaxAge() * 1000 + System.currentTimeMillis()

and then call apacheCookie.setExpiryDate(new Date([what you get from formula above]))

Answer (score 0):

To convert from HttpCookie to a BasicClientCookie you can use reflection to get the cookie creation time from the HttpCookie object. then add the max age to the creation time to get the actual expiration time (the other direction is simpler since you have the creation time which is the time you created the cookie for the conversion. otherwise use reflection to get it in the same way):

```
try {
    Field whenCreatedField;
    long whenCreated;
    whenCreatedField = HttpCookie.class.getDeclaredField("whenCreated");
    whenCreatedField.setAccessible(true);
    whenCreated = (Long) whenCreatedField.get(httpCookie);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(whenCreated + httpCookie.getMaxAge());

    apacheCookie.setExpiryDate(calendar.getTime());
} catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```